# Visual Studio Code analysis - Creating a new rule to count number of lines in methods

Tags: c#, code-analysis

**UPDATE**

**I reflected Microsoft.Cci.dll and build my rule. It works fine. However, I am facing some problem which I put [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/70a7a2d8-9246-4d49-b504-3fec14b8b0d7/?prof=required&lc=1033) with all the details. Source code is [here](http://4lyjtq.blu.livefilestore.com/y1ptWgIweqUKSdgxADEv_HqLiSW3IlAUNNfKo_Kc-Gx-3-nNhQ_m1c18jFflS7HICCmC8htbjFOs4Tj25whAJPHDrjak-fym9mX/EnforceLOCLimitRule.zip?download&psid=1). I didn't want to increase the length of this question by putting all the details.**

I am trying to write a code analysis rule which would raise warnings for methods having 
more than 100 lines. I am following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) article. However, I am unable to count the number of lines by following the API provided by  CodeAnalysis. for example,

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
        {
            Method method = member as Method;
            if (method == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            CheckForLOC(method);
            return Problems;
        }
```

Following is the CheckForLOC()

```
private void CheckForLOC(Method method)
    {
        int startLineForMethod = method.Body.SourceContext.StartLine;
        int endLineForMethod = method.Body.SourceContext.EndLine;
        if (endLineForMethod > startLineForMethod
            && ((endLineForMethod - startLineForMethod) > constMaximumLOCforAMethod))
        {
            Resolution resolution = GetResolution(method, constMaximumLOCforAMethod);
            Problem problem = new Problem(resolution);
            Problems.Add(problem);
        }
    }
```

In the above code, method.Body.SourceContext.StartLine and method.Body.SourceContext.EndLine return the same value. Not sure why.

I also tried using the StatementCollection :-

```
private void CheckForLOC(Method method)
        {
            int LOCPerMethod = 0;

            if (method.Body.Statements.Count >= 1)
            {
                foreach (var statement in method.Body.Statements)
                {
                    LOCPerMethod += GetNumberOfLinesPerStatement(statement);
                }

            }
            if (LOCPerMethod > constMaximumLOCforAMethod)
            {
                Resolution resolution = GetResolution(method, constMaximumLOCforAMethod);
                Problem problem = new Problem(resolution);
                Problems.Add(problem);
            }
        }

        private int GetNumberOfLinesPerStatement(Statement statement)
        {
            int LOCperStatement = 0;
            if (statement.SourceContext.EndLine > statement.SourceContext.StartLine)
            {
                LOCperStatement = statement.SourceContext.EndLine - statement.SourceContext.StartLine;
            }
            return LOCperStatement;
        }
```

Here also, Statement.SourceContext.StartLine and Statement.SourceContext.EndLine return the same value. I see that the StartLine for each statement is different and one needs to substract the StartLine value of the one statement from its previous one's. However, I see that result is erratic. For example, in the below snippet in a method, It gives me the line number of Statement1 as StartLineNumber whereas It should give the StartLineNumber of If(SomeCondition):-

```
if(SomeCondition)
{
   Statement1
   Statement2
   Statement3
}
```

Could anybody provide some direction on this?

Comment: While this doesn’t answer your question, you could take a look at the tool NDepend (www.ndepend.com). It’s commercial code metrics tool that has a method size metric and many many more.

Comment: @Steven, thanks for your time and the comments. Actually Visual Studio also has "Code Metrics" feature available. However, I wanted to build a rule which we can all follow and that should get integrated with the VS solution just like any other code analysis rule does. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to sound like a salesman now, but you can integrate NDepend with Visual Studio and your automated build process. However, having a license for each developer on the team can be a bit pricy :-). I wanting to have such a rule is a good thing, but isn't 100 lines a bit large? I try to have my methods under 10 lines of code on average.

Comment: Ok, @Steven, the Salesman...:-) I am not sure If I can convince my manager for NDepend at this point of time. And 100 is just a number. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a style rule than a correctness rule, so it would be a better candidate for a StyleCop rule than an FxCop rule.

That said, if you really want to implement it via FxCop, you should take a look at how the Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodMetrics.CalculateLinesOfCode(Method) accomplishes the same task.

Comment: I dont see Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodMetrics when I reflect FxCop.dll. Could you provide directions on where you saw that class?

Comment: It's in the Microsoft.Cci assembly.

Comment: @nicole - What version of Cci is this in? I don't see it in mine. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Microsoft.Cci.dll`

Comment: @Maslow: Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodMetrics.CalculateLinesOfCode(Method) is present in both the VS2008/FxCop 1.36 and VS2010/FxCop 10 versions of Microsoft.Cci.  However, the Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodMetrics class has internal visibility, which may be why you're not "seeing" it (depending on how you're attempting to find it).

Comment: @Maslow, Use RedGate Reflector to find the method. You can also use the disassembler - http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The tool NDepend supports the metric [NbLinesOfCode](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfCode) on any .NET language. Also, it integrates in Visual Studio 2012, 2010, 2008.  *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

You are asking for...

> Creating a new rule to count number of lines in methods

With NDepend you can write [Code Rules over LINQ Queries (namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Hence creating a new rule to count number of lines in methods, can be as simple as writing...

```
warnif count > 0 
from m in JustMyCode.Methods
where m.NbLinesOfCode > 10
orderby m.NbLinesOfCode descending 
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

...and get an immediate result in Visual Studio. Just by double-clicking a method in the result jumps to the method declaration in code:

[image]

Around [200 default CQLinq code queries and rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default.

Comment: You know, I would love to use NDepend. Thats commercial product and the management might not agree for this, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: With a pricing starting at a few hundreds bucks hopefully the tool should pay off in less than a month.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same (to get total no of lines in a method) and I found solution.

Below is the sample:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        Method method = member as Method;
        if (method != null)
        {
            **if (method.Metrics.ClassCoupling > 20)**
            {
                Resolution resolu = GetResolution(new string[] { method.ToString() });
                Problems.Add(new Problem(resolu));
            }
        }
        return Problems;
    }
```

You can try **method.Metrics.ClassCoupling** to get the total lines a method.